# how to get the node's Attribute in ASP.NET?

Tags: c#, asp.net, xml, xmlreader

I have a XML file and i want to read it and save the result into datatable, here is my XML file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" standalone="yes"?>
<NewDataSet>
  <Table name="tblAdminUser">
<Column>
  <displayname>
    Created Date
  </displayname>
  <orignalvalue>
    Created_Date
  </orignalvalue>
</Column>
<Column>
  <displayname>
    First Name
  </displayname>
  <orignalvalue>
    F_Name
  </orignalvalue>
</Column>
  </Table>
<Table name="test1">
   <Column> 
     <displayname>
    Last Name
  </displayname>
  <orignalvalue>
    L_Name
  </orignalvalue>
</Column>
<Column>
  <displayname>
    Created By
  </displayname>
  <orignalvalue>
    Created_By
  </orignalvalue>
</Column>
  </Table>
</NewDataSet>
```

Now what i want to do is:

If the "**Name**" of "table" node is "tblAdminuser" then i want to get the "**display column**" node's inner values and corresponding "original value" in a Datatable in two columns.

What i have done up to now is:

```
XmlDataDocument xmldoc = new XmlDataDocument();
    xmldoc.Load(Server.MapPath("~/XMLFile.xml"));
    XmlElement root = xmldoc.DocumentElement;
    XmlNodeList tablenodes = root.SelectNodes("Table");
    foreach (XmlNode nodes in tablenodes)
    {

        if (nodes.LocalName == "tblAdminUser")
        {
            XmlNodeList Columnnodes = root.SelectNodes("Column"); // You can also use XPath here
            XmlNodeList displayColumnnodes = root.SelectNodes("Column");
            foreach (XmlNode node in displayColumnnodes)
            {
                Response.Write(node.InnerText);
                // use node variable here for your beeds
            }
        }
    }
```

Please help me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is my code to full fill my requirement :

```
using System;
using System.Xml;
using System.Web;
using System.Data;

public class ClsXML
{
public DataTable GetColumnsFromXML(String XMLPath, String TableName)
{
    DataTable dtForColumns = DatatableforColumns();
    XmlDataDocument xmldoc = new XmlDataDocument();
    xmldoc.Load(XMLPath);
    XmlElement root = xmldoc.DocumentElement;
    XmlNodeList tablenodes = root.SelectNodes("Table");

    if (tablenodes != null)

        foreach (XmlNode nodes in tablenodes)
        {
            if (!nodes.HasChildNodes) continue;
            if (nodes.Attributes == null) continue;
            //TableName = nodes.Attributes[0].Value;

            if (nodes.Attributes[0].Value == TableName)
            {
                String PrimaryKey = nodes.Attributes[1].Value;
                var nodesdisplayname = nodes.SelectNodes("Column/DisplayColumn");
                var nodesorignalvalue = nodes.SelectNodes("Column/OrignalColumn");

                if (nodesdisplayname != null && nodesorignalvalue != null)
                {
                    for (int i = 0; i <= nodesdisplayname.Count - 1; i++)
                    {
                        var xmlDisplayNode = nodesdisplayname.Item(i);
                        var xmlOrignalNode = nodesorignalvalue.Item(i);


                        if (xmlDisplayNode != null && xmlOrignalNode != null)
                        {

                            DataRow dr;
                            dr = dtForColumns.NewRow();
                            dr["DisplayColumn"] = xmlDisplayNode.InnerText;
                            dr["OrignalColumn"] = xmlOrignalNode.InnerText;
                            dr["PrimaryKey"] = PrimaryKey;
                            dtForColumns.Rows.Add(dr);
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    return dtForColumns;
}
private DataTable DatatableforColumns()
{
    DataTable dt = new DataTable();
    dt.Columns.Add("DisplayColumn", typeof(String));
    dt.Columns.Add("OrignalColumn", typeof(String));
    dt.Columns.Add("PrimaryKey", typeof(String));
    return dt;
}
}
```

Thanks all happy code....

Answer (score 2):

Try This

```
XmlDataDocument xmldoc = new XmlDataDocument();
            xmldoc.Load("C:/test.xml");
            var root = xmldoc.DocumentElement;
            if (root == null) return;
            var users = new List<User>();

            var tablenodes = root.SelectNodes("Table");
            if (tablenodes != null)

                foreach (XmlNode nodes in tablenodes)
                {
                    if (!nodes.HasChildNodes) continue;

                    if (nodes.Attributes == null) continue;
                    var user = new User { UserName = nodes.Attributes[0].Value };
                    var customer = new Customer();

                    var nodesdisplayname = nodes.SelectNodes("Column/displayname");

                    if (nodesdisplayname != null)
                    {
                        var xmlNode = nodesdisplayname.Item(0);
                        if (xmlNode != null)
                        {
                            customer.DisplayName  = xmlNode.InnerText;
                        }
                    }

                    var nodesorignalvalue = nodes.SelectNodes("Column/orignalvalue");

                    if (nodesorignalvalue != null)
                    {
                        var xmlNode = nodesorignalvalue.Item(0);
                        if (xmlNode != null)
                        {
                            customer.OriginalValue = xmlNode.InnerText;
                        }
                    }

                    user.Customers = customer;
                    users.Add(user);
                }
```

Also add condition in above code as

```
if(nodes.Attributes[0].Value == "tblAdminUser")
{
  // Added code here
}
```

And take user and customer class as example

```
  public class User
    {
        public Customer Customers;

        public string UserName { get; set; }
    }

    public class Customer
    {
        public string DisplayName { get; set; }

        public string OriginalValue { get; set; }
    }
```

It will return list of user.

I suppose it will help.

Comment: it does not meet my requirement but it provided me the row material to full fill my requirement. So +1 for that

Comment: Ok well , this code return list and you required datatable. Thanks for +1

Answer (score 2):

Seems like a better XPath statement would help out.

You have

> root.SelectNodes("Table");

Change to

> root.SelectNodes( "//Table[(@name='tblAdminUser')]/Column" )

You might consider **XSLT**, here's a sample

```
<?xml version='1.0'?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes" omit-xml-declaration="yes"/>
<xsl:template match='/'>

<table>
    <tr>
        <th>Display Name</th>
        <th>Original Value</th>
    </tr>

    <xsl:for-each select='//Table[(@name="tblAdminUser")]/Column'>
    <tr>
        <td><xsl:value-of select='displayname'/></td>
        <td><xsl:value-of select='orignalvalue'/></td>
    </tr>
    </xsl:for-each>

</table>

</xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```